# How do I overcome Python http.client.HTTPResponse objects?

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.4

I have tried to get response from a url, from the following code.
I am using Python 3.x

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url_getallfolders = 'https://qa.wittyparrot.com/alfresco/service/acrowit/userfolderinfo?access_token=TICKET_83361146b0e140f48ba404c3d8457452a92e117f'
x = urlopen(url_getallfolders)
print(x)
```

I get the following error:

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x030304B0>
```

I even tried with urllib.urlopen:

```
x = urllib.urlopen(url_getallfolders)
print(x)
```

then i get this error:

```
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not an error. It is the expected response object. You probably want to read the documentation in more detail.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You did not get an error, you instead got an expected response object. If you wanted to access the data from the response then you need to *read* from that object, or inspect the headers and status code perhaps.

Reading the response body data is as simple as:

```
x = urlopen(url_getallfolders)
data = x.read()
```

From the [`urllib.request.urlopen()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

> For http and https urls, this function returns a `http.client.HTTPResponse` object which has the following *[`HTTPResponse` Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects)* methods.

where I used the [`HTTPResponse.read()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read) above.

Note that the result will be *encoded bytes*, if you expected text you'll still need to decode that text. The URL you called returns JSON, so you probably want to decode that to Python:

```
import json

x = urlopen(url_getallfolders)
raw_data = x.read()
encoding = x.info().get_content_charset('utf8')  # JSON default
data = json.loads(raw_data.decode(encoding))
```

after which you can access keys such as `'error'`, `'errorList'`, `'respList'` and `'warning'`.

Comment: Thanks.Now i get the byte literals along with my output. b'<myoutput>

Answer (score 3):

If you just want super basic command-line oriented, HTTP-client functionality, like `curl` or `wget` (the popular CLI utilities) without any options; where you feed it a URL, and it simply returns plaintext and HTML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('https://example.com') as x:
     data = x.read().decode('utf-8')

print(data)
```

If you want the byte objects, just drop the `.decode('utf-8')` so it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('https://example.com') as x:
     data = x.read()

print(data)
```

I've tried to reduce it to as few lines as possible. Feel free to define your variables (URLs, etc.) separately.